# List of prioritized targets in the United States

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, nuclear-weapons

Is there a list of prioritized strategic targets in the United States? I live near a former military base that is probably a secondary or tertiary target, so I am wondering where it is on the list and how many nuclear weapons the Russians have total on their subs, so I can guess the probability of my area getting targeted in the event of a war.

Comment: You can sleep pretty well, I think.  Risks were much higher in the 70s and 80s and we survived just fine.  This whole Ukraine media hysteria is pretty fascinating, with every mainstream publication under the sun reinventing itself as a military think tank peddling doom and gloom.  No DV, but... for a **former** military base to get targeted, there would be so much crap flying around that the old nuclear winter theories and/or the subsequent industrial collapse would get you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a strategic decision of the **Russians** and secret. So you would need an [informed](https://www.armscontrol.org/factsheets/Nuclearweaponswhohaswhat) [guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Rocket_Forces#Numbers_of_missiles_and_warheads) about what the Russians have (treaties give a legal maximum, and they are supposed to declare actual numbers), and how much faith they have in the reliability of their systems and the absence of a missile defense, to find out how many launchers they allocate to each target. Then you would have to guess their priorities.

But to reassure you a little, we may be seeing the [stability-instability-paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability%E2%80%93instability_paradox) in action. Mutual MAD means the Russians can risk provocations in Ukraine.